# Why don't I have access to the database from aws lambda but have from a local computer with the same login data?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymysql

I created a new Mysql database in Amazon RDS, and on my local computer I get access through the console

```
mysql -u username -p -h test.c2nfdg67dbdpb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

Now I try to connect via Aws Lamda using python and pymysql module

```
rds_host  = "test.c2nfdg67dbdpb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
name = 'username'
password = 'pass'
db_name = 'dbtest'

conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5)
```

and got an error `ERROR]    2019-11-20T14:30:05.261Z    7b1ed2e0-03ba-4c62-9525-22d84582f   (1049, "Unknown database 'dbtest'")`

It seems strange that I don't use the database name at all through the local console and I get access.

p.s.I run `show databases;` on local console and cant see `dbtest` in databaselist. I was confused because when I created the new database, I entered a name, but only default databases are listed. What am I connected to then?

p.s.s
hm why DB name is undefined ?

[image]

Comment: similar to this maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610344/using-pymysql-i-cant-connect-to-rds

Comment: You mention `db_test` is missing from `show databases;` but your code tries to connect to `dbtest` (no underscore). Please clarify.

Comment: @Cascader I made a mistake in the question, corrected it.

Comment: @Jekson, there seems to be a contradiction in your question. How can you establish a successful connection to a non-existing database from your local computer?

Answer (score 1):

Your code explicitly tries to connect a specific database named `dbtest`. It will either connect to this database or fail, contrary to your mysql client which can connect without a database selection. Clearly, the database is missing, since you verified that `show databases` results does not include `dbtest`.

Then only possible explanation is that the database was never created.

Comment: Cascader, The RDS console provides the ability to create a database with default settings. That's the way I used it. But no physical database is created, only database instances are created.

Comment: I see now. If for some reason the database was not created within the instance, I might open a support case with AWS RDS team. There is nothing more you can do and they might need to investigate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The RDS console provides the ability to create a database with default settings. That's the way I used it. But no physical database is created, only database instances.

I can't found a way to add a new database to the created instance. Now, after a few hours of troubleshooting, I recreated the new database without using the default settings and there was a point - **database name** entry. I added this name and everything worked out.

But here's what I don't understand is why AWS added a quick creation way, which in the end doesn't actually create a database that you can join.

Comment: "I can't found a way to add a new database to the created instance." Just connect to it and issue the query `CREATE DATABASE foo`.

Comment: Omm, yes. I looked the way from RDS web interface,but nothing.

Comment: The RDS web interface isn't really intended for DBA tasks. It manages the server itself. The databases, tables, and data are up to you.

Answer (score -2):

If you have created the database in Amazon RDS and are able to connect to it from your local computer, it may be a **connection/permission issue** with your lambda. Your Lambda function may be inside a VPC subnet with no internet access.  Either **pull it out of the VPC** or **grant internet access to the Lambda function** like this:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

However, if your Lambda function will be communicating with RDS instances, you should consider doing this via private channels for security purposes.

### Update

A third possibility is that **the database in question doesn't exist** even though the asker implies that there was a successful connection to the database from his/her local computer.

Comment: You would not get the message `Unknown database 'dbtest'` in this case.

Comment: @ceejayoz, the subject line and actual question imply that there is connection from a local computer; therefore, I immediately ruled out the possibility of the database not being created and thought about a potential connection/permissions issue.